# Who is watching this page?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a way to know how many people are on a specific page of a joomla site and to display the result in a module. i own a chess site with live chess broadcast facility. I would be cool if on that page, there would be something like 3 members and 12 guest are watching

I am on joomla 3.4.1

I look forward to reading from you

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Have you simplied tried looking for Joomla extensions that display online users? There are quite a few of them. There is even one that comes pre-installed with Joomla

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Google Analytics API to retrieve real time data and embed this into your Joomla page.

A quick Google has returned these which you may want to look at;

[Analytics Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/)

[EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalytics-realtime-reporting.html)

This suggestion obviously won't show you guests and members, it will simply display how many members are on a specific page (which you retrieve from the API).

Personally I haven't used the Google API for this purpose but it shouldn't be that difficult to do and the documentation seems pretty good.

Hope this helps. Please let us know if you get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just install and configure built-in module Who's Online

Comment: this only tells you who is online on the site not who is at a specifuc page of the site

Comment: For that, my friend, you won't find any extension... trust me...